# Working with suds objects

Tags: python, soap, suds

I'm using the Web of Science API and suds to retrieve article records. I'd like to create a list containing all distinct ISSNs, but I'm having trouble accessing this data within the suds object. Here is what the complete response looks like for one record:

```
(searchResults){
   queryId = "1"
   recordsFound = 16922
   recordsSearched = 52057936
   records[] = 
      (liteRecord){
         uid = "WOS:000086498700003"
         title[] = 
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Title"
               value[] = 
                  "Why young people do not kill themselves: The Reasons for Living Inventory for Adolescents",
            },
         source[] = 
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Issue"
               value[] = 
                  "2",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Pages"
               value[] = 
                  "177-187",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Published.BiblioDate"
               value[] = 
                  "JUN",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Published.BiblioYear"
               value[] = 
                  "2000",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "SourceTitle"
               value[] = 
                  "JOURNAL OF CLINICAL CHILD PSYCHOLOGY",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Volume"
               value[] = 
                  "29",
            },
         authors[] = 
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Authors"
               value[] = 
                  "Gutierrez, PM",
                  "Osman, A",
                  "Kopper, BA",
                  "Barrios, FX",
            },
         other[] = 
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Identifier.Ids"
               value[] = 
                  "304RV",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Identifier.Issn"
               value[] = 
                  "0047-228X",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "Identifier.Xref_Doi"
               value[] = 
                  "10.1207/S15374424jccp2902_4",
            },
            (labelValuesPair){
               label = "ResearcherID.Disclaimer"
               value[] = 
                  "ResearcherID data provided by Thomson Reuters",
            },
      },
 }
```

I can retrieve all of the `other` lists, but I'm not sure how to identify and retrieve the ISSN by label so that I can add it to the list. The type given is: suds.sudsobject.labelValuePair. IANAP and have only a basic familiarity with Python, so I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
soap = wos.WokmwsSoapClient()
results = soap.search(YOUR QUERY HERE)
for i in range(0, len(results.records[0].other)):
    if results.records[0].other[i]["label"] == "Identifier.Issn":
        print results.records[0].other[i]["value"][0]
```